# Node can't find Web3 js

Tags: node.js, web3js

I'm kind of new to Node. So, I installed Web3 like this:

```
npm install -g web3
```

Success. Then I run node and try to require web3. It doesn't work:

```
Welcome to Node.js v12.11.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> Web3 = require('web3')
Thrown:
Error: Cannot find module 'web3'
Require stack:
- <repl>
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:780:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:838:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '<repl>' ]
}
```

Any ideas, I'm probably missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the web3 has problems when you globally install it using `-g`.

I suggest you give `npm init` to your project if you have not already given it and install it only for your project running:

```
npm install web3
```

inside of your project folder.